# Getting the Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR. An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80004005

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, ssis, ssis-2019

I am creating a new SSIS package, about 25 data flows. From Oracle database to SQL Server.
IT always fails. Each container has about 8 data flows.
[image]

When I run it, I always get the same error for different data flows.
[image]

These are  the errors:

```
[Pull SKU [518]] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80004005.
[SSIS.Pipeline] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PRIMEOUTPUTFAILED.  The PrimeOutput method on Pull SKU returned error code 0xC0202009.
```

The component returned a failure code when the pipeline engine called `PrimeOutput()`. The meaning of the failure code is defined by the component, but the error is fatal and the pipeline stopped executing.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.
Any ideas as to what is wrong here?

Comment: it could be a few things, from environmental to casting. One way to isolate the issue is to disable all the data flows but one that has failed at some point,. Then run the process with the data viewer between source and destination enabled so you can see what is causing the issue

Comment: The problem is, that it is not the same data flow. One data flow might work on a first run and then fail on a second one...

Comment: Are the dataflows inside the containers also running in parallel? if so, the buffer might get fully allocated, and then some dataflows run and the others wait until there is buffer space, that would make the failure appear random as the processing order won't always be the same.